# Alchemy Error: what is the meaning of this -> maxFeePerGas cannot be less than maxPriorityFeePerGas

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I am following this tutorial -> https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/tutorials/sending-txs
The only difference is that i am trying to eth to ropsten test faucet

```
async function main() {
  require('dotenv').config();
  const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
  const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require('@alch/alchemy-web3');
  const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(API_URL);
  const myAddress = 'xxxx'; //TODO: replace this address with your own public address

  const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress, 'latest'); // nonce starts counting from 0
  console.log(nonce);
  const transaction = {
    to: '0x9f1099b301716892d17d576387027cE5B73E2c20', // faucet address to return eth
    value: 100,
    gas: 30000,
    maxFeePerGas: 1000000108,
    nonce: nonce,
    // optional data field to send message or execute smart contract
  };

  const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
    transaction,
    PRIVATE_KEY
  );

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
    signedTx.rawTransaction,
    function (error, hash) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log(
          ' The hash of your transaction is: ',
          hash,
          "\n Check Alchemy's Mempool to view the status of your transaction!"
        );
      } else {
        console.log(
          '❗Something went wrong while submitting your transaction:',
          error
        );
      }
    }
  );
}

main();
```

When i am running code i am getting this error -> `Error: maxFeePerGas cannot be less than maxPriorityFeePerGas (The total must be the larger of the two) (tx type=2 hash=not available (unsigned) nonce=23 value=100 signed=false hf=london maxFeePerGas=1000000108 maxPriorityFeePerGas=2500000000)`

Update : if i replace `maxFeePerGas` with `maxPriorityFeePerGas` this works

**What am i missing conceptually?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the default value of `maxPriorityFeePerGas` was changed from `1.0 gwei` to `2.5 gwei` due to some incentive mechanism for miners.

Follow this [issue](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/4283) for more detailed information.

Hence, if we don't set the `maxPriorityFeePerGas` parameter, the default value `2.5 gwei` would larger than `maxFeePerGas`, which is `1.0 gwei` we set and violate the rule.

We can solve this issue by either setting `maxPriorityFeePerGas` smaller than `1.0 gwei` or changing `maxFeePerGas` larger than `2.5 gwei`.